# MongoDB-- equivalent Java Code for mongoDB

Tags: java, mongodb

I have this following below query , can anyone tell me how to write equivalent java code for `MongoDB` aggregation function

```
db.File.aggregate([{$project:{_id:1 , days:{$multiply:[ {$subtract:["$col2","$col1"]},1/(1000*60*60*24)]})
```

Comment: Are you looking for how to perform a MongoDB aggregation query in Java or to implement the actual aggregation in Java without using Mongo?

Answer (score 0):

If you can implement it in Java 8 you could use the Stream API and call map() function to perform your calculation on File collection items.
I assume you first deserialize the JSON documents from MongoDB to a collection of Java objects.

Comment: Sorry , I am using Java 6 . Is there anyway to do by this .

Comment: Yes, but you have to iterate through a collection of Java objects and perform calculation. The query above perform the multiplication of first term which is the result of a substraction and second term which is a constant value. Result seems to be a number of days.